# Passing console.log an object returns differently when using two arguments - why?

Tags: javascript, object, arguments, console.log

I've been using console.log to log an object, and noticed that it doesn't return the value of the object unless the object is its own argument in console.log. Why does this happen?

```
const obj = {animal: "Dog"};

console.log("obj:", obj);   //returns { animal: 'Dog' }
console.log("obj: " + obj); //returns obj: [object Object]
console.log(`obj: ${obj}`); //returns obj: [object Object]
```

Comment: when you are explicitly concatenating the two, `obj` will be converted to its string representation, aka `obj.toString()`, which will be `[object Object]`.

Comment: @KevinQian Why did you post this answer as a comment?

Comment: @Luca Sorry, will move to answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are explicitly concatenating the two, obj will be converted to its string representation, aka `obj.toString()`, which will be `[object Object]`.

To make things more interesting, we can check how `console.log()` works, for example in Node. It uses `util.format()` to format the output. If it detects it as NOT a simple string, it `inspect`s the object and decide on further steps. See https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L169

Comment: Oh, right. I might have figured that out in a while - I never thought about the fact that I was concatenating it! Thank you!